# Statsmodels: How to use get_rdataset

Tags: python, dataset, statsmodels

every time I try to use sm.datasets.get_rdataset I get the error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name get_rdataset
```

I am using the latest version of statsmodels (0.5.0.dev-1bbd4ca) which I installed using pip. I see in the installation logs that pip downloads the sources from github.

I would be very thankful for your help

Andy

Answer (score 0):

This version is still too old. You'll need to install from github.

Comment: Hi Skipper, thanks for the hint. However, everytime I try to install from github I run into the error message:    bash-3.2$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7 setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 476, in <module>
    write_version_py()
  File "setup.py", line 232, in write_version_py
    a.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment      --- Can you help me with that?

Comment: A patch here would be welcome. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/843

Answer (score 0):

Followings are part of the `setup.py`

```
if dowrite:
    try:
        a = open(filename, 'w')
        a.write(cnt % {'version': VERSION,
                       'full_version' : FULLVERSION,
                       'git_revision' : GIT_REVISION,
                       'isrelease': str(ISRELEASED)})
    finally:
        a.close()
```

Seems it got some problems while opening the file, and then jump into finally block. Probably caused by the permission issue. Check the permission of your coes. You can also remove the try,finally pair so that the exception message will be shown in your console directly.